# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 issue in glassfish. How do i resolve?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, glassfish

I am new at both linux and glassfish, I am trying to deploy this .war project I made in Eclipse Kepler. But I get the following error while deploying:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Then I go to server log and I find the following:-

```
[#|2015-06-01T14:04:02.926+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.ssl.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.impl|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC5054: Certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23741889829347261660812437366387754385443431973861114865490414153884050331745811968523116847625570146592736935209718565296053386842135985534863157983128812774162998053673746470782252407673402238146869994438729551246768368782318393878374421033907597162218758024581735139682087126982809511479059100617027892880227587855877479432885604404402435662802390484099065871430585284534529627347717530352189612077130606642676951640071336717026459037542552927905851171460589361570392199748753414855675665635003335769915908187224347232807336022456537328962095005323382940080676931822787496212635993279098588863972868266229522169377
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Aug 14 16:50:00 CEST 1998,
               To: Thu Aug 15 01:59:00 CEST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    01b6]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:5
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.2.840.113763.1.2.1.3]
[]  ]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 76 0A 49 21 38 4C 9F DE   F8 C4 49 C7 71 71 91 9D  v.I!8L....I.qq..
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 41 3A D4 18 5B DA B8 DE   21 1C E1 8E 09 E5 F1 68  A:..[...!......h
0010: 34 FF DE 96 F4 07 F5 A7   3C F3 AC 4A B1 9B FA 92  4.......<..J....
0020: FA 9B ED E6 32 21 AA 4A   76 C5 DC 4F 38 E5 DF D5  ....2!.Jv..O8...
0030: 86 E4 D5 C8 76 7D 98 D7   B1 CD 8F 4D B5 91 23 6C  ....v......M..#l
0040: 8B 8A EB EA 7C EF 14 94   C4 C6 F0 1F 4A 2D 32 71  ............J-2q
0050: 63 2B 63 91 26 02 09 B6   80 1D ED E2 CC B8 7F DB  c+c.&...........
0060: 87 63 C8 E1 D0 6C 26 B1   35 1D 40 66 10 1B CD 95  .c...l&.5.@f....
0070: 54 18 33 61 EC 13 4F DA   13 F7 99 AF 3E D0 CF 8E  T.3a..O.....>...
0080: A6 72 A2 B3 C3 05 9A C9   27 7D 92 CC 7E 52 8D B3  .r......'....R..
0090: AB 70 6D 9E 89 9F 4D EB   1A 75 C2 98 AA D5 02 16  .pm...M..u......
00A0: D7 0C 8A BF 25 E4 EB 2D   BC 98 E9 58 38 19 7C B9  ....%..-...X8...
00B0: 37 FE DB E2 99 08 73 06   C7 97 83 6A 7D 10 01 2F  7.....s....j.../
00C0: 32 B9 17 05 4A 65 E6 2F   CE BE 5E 53 A6 82 E9 9A  2...Je./..^S....
00D0: 53 0A 84 74 2D 83 CA C8   94 16 76 5F 94 61 28 F0  S..t-.....v_.a(.
00E0: 85 A7 39 BB D7 8B D9 A8   B2 13 1D 54 09 34 24 7D  ..9........T.4$.
00F0: 20 81 7D 66 7E A2 90 74   5C 10 C6 BD EC AB 1B C2   ..f...t\.......

]|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:02.934+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Redirecting to /common/applications/uploadFrame.jsf?form:title2:bottomButtons:uploadButton=Processing...&bare=false|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:02.994+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:23.003+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:23.056+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:23.057+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|uploadFileName=CompactSpring.war|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:34.120+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:34.363+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:218)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.apply(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:100)
    at com.google.common.collect.MapMaker$ComputingMapAdapter.get(MapMaker.java:515)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:206)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.apply(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:100)
    at com.google.common.collect.MapMaker$ComputingMapAdapter.get(MapMaker.java:515)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:206)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.apply(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:100)
    at com.google.common.collect.MapMaker$ComputingMapAdapter.get(MapMaker.java:515)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldConstructorImpl.<init>(WeldConstructorImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldConstructorImpl.of(WeldConstructorImpl.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:206)
    ... 78 more
|#]

[#|2015-06-01T14:04:34.401+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3. Please see server.log for more details.|#]
```

**I dont understand why the 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3' is appearing because this error doesn't exist when I debug the project in eclipse.**

**EDIT1:** As requested here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rs.fispace</groupId>
    <artifactId>trace</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>core</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <postgresql-version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</postgresql-version>
        <spring-release-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-release-version>
        <log4j-release-version>2.1</log4j-release-version>
        <junit-release-version>4.12</junit-release-version>
        <springsecurity.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-release-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- postgresql database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is the other pom.xml (I wanst sure which one to post here):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.fispace.apps</groupId>
    <artifactId>CompactSpring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <descriptor>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                        <contextPath>/fispace-app-compact</contextPath>
                        <extraClasspath>target/classes</extraClasspath>

                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <apache-tiles.version>3.0.5</apache-tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.fispace</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.0-S1513</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.limetri.ygg</groupId>
            <artifactId>ygg-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-servlet-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.limetri.ygg</groupId>
            <artifactId>ygg-auth-keycloak</artifactId>
            <version>0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>rs.fispace</groupId>
            <artifactId>trace</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You are trying to access an element from an array which is not in the array. That is why the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Comment: So you think it is in the code and nothing to do with glass-fish configuration?
I'm just scratching my head because the debug doesn't report any errors.

Comment: Are you using Guava? I've read there might be some conflict on some versions.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue I doubt Im using Guava since I dont even know what it is.

Comment: Note that the problem isn't directly in your code as mentioned by @PHJCJO. None of your class (unless you work for google) is shown in the stack. This problem certainly is caused by a library.

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml` to the question if you have a maven-based project or show us your project dependencies if you don't have a maven-based project.

Comment: @unwichtich I added the 2 pom.xml I have

Comment: Why do you have the jetty-maven-plugin in your pom.xml if you want to deploy to Glassfish? This doesn't really makes sense.

Comment: @unwichtich Because I was testing the project on jetty from command prompt, now I want to test it by deploying on glass-fish. I have checked the version of my glassfish: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build 23). Is this a good place to look up my pom.xml settings for glassfish?:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1754/6nmnfdnls/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was creating the project on one machine using jdk8 and then tried to deploy it on another machine in glass-fish version 3 which was running on jdk6. I then simply switched to glass-fish version 4 and jdk8 and it is running ok now.

Answer (score 1):

The Exceptions concerning "Certificate has expired" on startup in Glassfish 3.x should not affect your code. Except if you are going to use this invalid SSL certificates.

The reason for this exceptions is, that the certificate keystore of Glassfish contains expired SSL certificates. In my case I just got rid of them an now the errors are gone.

To remove them, you just have to navigate - using commandline - to the Glassfish directory where the file **cacerts.jks** is located (for example **glassfish/domains/domain1/config/**.
There you execute the following statement:

```
/opt/jre/bin/keytool -delete -alias gtecybertrust5ca -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass changeit
```

Note that '/opt/jre/bin/keytool' could be an alternative path, it depends on where your Java installation is located.

After that, you need to restart Glassfish and the certificate errors should be gone.

Comment: thanks for the input but it was just the mixed up versions of glassfish and jdk